# SQL IMDB website query to find actors starred in at least 10 movies

Tags: mysql, sql, actor, movie

Using the ER diagram of IMBD I need to find the time period in which each actor was active, by listing the earliest and the latest year in which the actor starred in a film, but only for the actors that have starred in at least 10 movies.

I wrote the part in regards to the period of acting, but am struggling with at least 10 movies one. I understand I should use HAVING COUNT

My answer so far is:

```
SELECT r.actor_id, min(m.year), max(m.year) 
FROM roles r 
LEFT JOIN movies m ON r.movie_id = m.id 
GROUP BY r.actor_id
```

[image: IMBD ER Diagram]

Comment: No need to use `LEFT JOIN`. `movie_id` is a foreign key, there has to be a matching movie.

Comment: SELECT r.actor_id, count(m.id), min(m.year), max(m.year) 
FROM roles r 
LEFT JOIN movies m ON r.movie_id = m.id 
GROUP BY r.actor_id
HAVING count(m.id) > 9; ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. As pointed out my Barmar you don't need the left join.

```
SELECT r.actor_id, min(m.year), max(m.year) 
FROM roles r 
GROUP BY r.actor_id
Having count(*) >= 10
```

In case if you ever have to change the table structure for roles to include the scenario of a single actor performing multiple roles then you might have to change your query like below:

```
SELECT r.actor_id, min(m.year), max(m.year) 
FROM roles r 
GROUP BY r.actor_id
Having count(distinct r.movie_id) >= 10
```

Comment: If I understand the diagram correctly, `(actor_id, movie_id)` is a unique key, so there can't be duplicates. So you don't need `DISTINCT`, it can just be `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Corrected. I just thought of a scenario where an actor is in multiple roles in a single movie in which case you might have to change the table structure. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought you were going for, and I was going to praise you for thinking of it (because I didn't!).